# Detecting a reflow or moving of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I built an UI widget that shows a floating popup beneath the actual widget. It uses absolute positioning to position itself beneath the widget. What I am concerned is that when the document layout changes a bit, the absolutely positioned element is not beneath my UI widget.

Is there a way to detect if an HTML element has moved or reflowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution.

Whenever the floating popup is shown, I create an interval that runs every 250 msec calculating its position again (if the position of the parent has changed). When the popup hides or closes, I end the timer.

Comment: In Firefox, you may want to try [MozAfterPaint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#MozAfterPaint) for better performance

Comment: This is the intuitive solution that we all get initially. I have the same problem as yours but don't want to do this solution because it's not good performance wise.

Answer (score 2):

How about using relative positioning and attaching your widget to the actual widget? That way it will always stay in the same position relative to the original widget.

Comment: I figured that too, but I need the popup to stay on the top of every other element on the page... and z-index is not working with relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the element to the body tag and position it on the page based on the position of the mouse. This is how jQuery UI Dialog and tooltip type scripts and such get around the z-index issue.

something like this if you have jQuery:

```
$('#clickelement').click(function(e){
     $('#yourlayer').appendTo('body').css({left: e.pageX + 'px',top: (e.pageY + 12) + 'px',zIndex:'10001'}).show();
});

#yourlayer{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
}
```

EDIT: fixed minor typo

Comment: I just realized this won't help if you mean reflow due to live resizing/reflowing. Maybe you could get the bottom position of your container element and use that to position your layer. I've never tried that before so am unsure if it is doable.